# Only Important notifications on Facebook

Tags: facebook

How do I change posts from friends to "only important"

Answer (score 2):

2 ways to select "Only Important" messages from your friends to appear in your newsfeed:

1. - Visit your friend's profile page
   - Hover over the "Friends" button under the cover photo
   - Under "Show in News Feed" select "Settings"
   - Select "Only Important
2. - On the friend's post in your Newsfeed, click on the arrow in the top right of the post
   - Click "Hide"
   - The now-hidden news story will show a menu; select "Change what updates you get from "
   - Select "Only Important"
   - You can also change what *types* of stories you get from this friend

Comment: This answer is no longer current - neither of those routes are available at the moment.